# Problem Comparing Value Returned by valueForKey Method of NSDictionary

Tags: nsdictionary, touchjson

I use TouchJSON to convert the following to an NSDictionary object

```
// sample JSON object
{
data =     (
            {
        companyId = 4779;
        companyName = "ABC Corporation";
    },
            {
        companyId = 4806;
        companyName = "EFG Corporation";
    }
);
dataCount = 2;
success = 1;
}

NSString *src = @"http://mysite/app1/companyList.php";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:src];    
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dic = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:data error:&error];

int dataCount = (int) [dic valueForKey:@"dataCount"];

// This is where I have problem with. The (dataCount == 1) expression never evaluates to true even if value of dataCount from the JSON object equals to 1.
if ( dataCount == 1 ){
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Have I done anything wrong?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

`[dic valueForKey:@"dataCount"]` will be an `NSNumber`. You'll need to call `-intValue` on it to get an `int`.

```
int dataCount = [[dic valueForKey:@"dataCount"] intValue];
if (dataCount == 1) {
    ... 
}
```